# How do I add my custom field in django filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API to return posts on a user profile. The posts can be public, friends only or with custom privacy. Here is my filter:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(created_by=user, privacy='PUBLIC') | 
            Q(created_by=user, privacy='FRIENDS')|
            Q(created_by=instance, privacy='CUSTOM', custom_list=requested_by.pk))
```

Here I want to get the 'friends_only' posts if the requested user is friend of the user whose profile I am showing. 
Problem is I don't have any relation between Post and Friend. I am using a Friend model as shown below:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="receiver", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)
```

and Post model as:

```
class Post(BaseModel, models.Model):
    PRIVACY_CHOICES = [
        ('PUBLIC', 'Public'),
        ('PRIVATE', 'Private'),
        ('FRIENDS', 'Friends only'),
        ('CUSTOM', 'Custom')
    ]
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="assets/posts/", null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    privacy = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PRIVACY_CHOICES)
    custom_list = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name="post_by_friends", blank=True)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name="likes", blank=True)
```

My question is how can I filter the Post model by providing my condition in filter *is_friend = True*

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you don't have a direct relationship between Post and Friend, but you do have an indirect one through UserProfile.

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(created_by=user, privacy='PUBLIC')
    | Q(created_by=user, privacy='FRIENDS')|
    | Q(
        Q(created_by__sender=user) | Q(created_by__receiver=user)
        created_by=instance, privacy='CUSTOM'
    )
).distinct()
```

You shouldn't need the `custom_list` ManyToManyField.